# How to fix empty output for the textfilestream code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

```
 object abc {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    m()
  }

  def m() {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ola").master("local[*]").getOrCreate
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
    var cnt = sc.longAccumulator("cnt")
    cnt.value

    import spark.implicits._
    val x = ssc.textFileStream("file:///home/xyz/folderone/")

    x.foreachRDD{ rddx =>
      val x2 = rddx.map { xxx =>
        cnt.add(1)
        xxx
      }
      x2.toDF.write.format("text").mode("overwrite").save("file:///home/xyz/oparekta")
    }
    println(s"value of count ${cnt.value}")
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }
```

above code is to process files from given folder path, somehow there is some issuein the code,  getting empty output file, what could be the reason?

Comment: May be because you are using overwrite mode. Try with append mode.

Comment: Tried with option write mode append but it's still producing empty output files although input files are non empty.

Comment: Any joy here to report?

Comment: not really. changed code to use structured streaming ,it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to avoid processing null data:

```
...
QS.foreachRDD(q => {
    if(!q.isEmpty) {   
...
```

Moreover, overwrite of append needs to be considered. Not sure of your use case, could be an oversight.